# Помогите перевести небольшой код из C в C#

Tags: c#, c

Данный код  рисует некий фрактал.

```
int main() {
    double a = 0.85, b = 0.9, k = 0.5, p = 7.7; // константы. При изменении их будет модифицироваться изображение
    complex z;
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    int i;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "G:\\programs\\BC31\\BGI"); // инициализируем графику
    z = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 30000; i++) {
        z = a + b * z * exp(complex(0, (k - p / (1 + abs(z * z))))); // формула, по которой рисуем
        putpixel(real(z) * 180 + 240, imag(z) * 180 + 280, 14); // ставим точку на экране
    }
    getch(); // пауза для задержки изображения на экране
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

Необходимо перевести в C#. Вот мои потуги. На данный момент есть ошибки. Никак не разберусь с этими комплексными числами.

```
private void MilkyMay()
{
    double a = 0.85, b = 0.9, k = 0.5, p = 7.7; // константы. При изменении их будет модифицироваться изображение         

    int i;
    milc = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height); // инициализируем графику
    Complex z = 0;
    Complex c;

    for (i = 0; i <= 30000; i++)
    {
        z = a + b * z * Math.Exp(c = new Complex (0, (k - p / (1 + Math.Abs(z * z))))); // формула, по которой рисуем
        milc.SetPixel(Convert.ToInt32(z.Real * 180 + 240), Convert.ToInt32(z.Imaginary * 180 + 280), Color.LawnGreen); // ставим точку на экране
    }

    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = milc;
}
```

Сейчас ошибка только в `Math.Abs(z * z)`,

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Numerics.Complex' to 'sbyte'

но и во всем остальном я не сильно уверен.

Comment: Вообще-то, в пример код на Си, а не на Delphi.

Comment: @zed Не исключаю. Но в данной http://www.opita.net/node/739 статье он находится в разделе Pascal/Delphi. Видимо там ошибка. Спасибо.

Comment: что за ошибка-то? и откуда взялось `c =` если в исходной формуле такого нет?

Comment: @Grundy ошибка выглядит так `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Numerics.Complex' to 'sbyte'`. Все верно, в оригинале просто `complex`. Т.е. очевидно новое комплексное число, и `(0, (k - p / (1 + Math.Abs(z * z)))))` - два его аргумента.  А то что у меня - это уже танцы с бубном.

Comment: убирай танцы и меняй `Math` на `Complex`

Comment: @GrundyСпасибо, заработало! Точно как в примере! Причем `c =new Complex` не убирал. Хоть и танцы, но верные. Всего то `Math` на `Сomplex` сменил.  Эх, как я был близок. Кстати, как отметить вопрос решенным?

Comment: @PavelSaenko, не не верные, если уберешь - все еще продолжит работать. просто не будет лишней переменной которую ты нигде не используешь

Comment: @Grundy первым же делом убрал. появилась ошибка. `Complex.Exp(0, (k - p / (1 + Complex.Abs(z * z))))` - в таком виде выдает "нет перегрузок Exp принимающих два аргумента" Вернул обратно - исчезла. Только после этого первый раз запустил.

Comment: Это все потому. что ты не то убрал что я сказал :-) я говорил только про `c = `

Comment: @Grundy Оформите комментарии как ответ или будем закрывать вопрос с формулировкой "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перевод верен, за исключением того, что для комплексных чисел нужно применять специальные методы находящиеся в [структуре Complex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.numerics.complex(v=vs.110).aspx), а именно:

1. [`Complex.Abs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.numerics.complex.abs(v=vs.110).aspx) - для получения модуля комплексной переменной
2. [`Complex.Exp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.numerics.complex.exp(v=vs.110).aspx) - для возведения экспоненты в комплексную степень.

Кроме этого, нет нужды в переменной `c`, которая нигде не используется.

В итоге все может выглядеть так:

```
z = a + b * z * Complex.Exp(new Complex(0, (k - p / (1 + Complex.Abs(z * z))))); // формула, по которой рисуем
```